# what is the meaning of "went off" in the context below?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning

Edmond halley, another famous astronomer, was born in London, England, in 1656. He studied astronomy at Oxford  University until  1676, when he **went off** to study the stars and planets of the southern hemisphere. Later He compiled his data in a book.

does it mean"when he finished university he continued to study about stars and planets of the southern hemisphere"?
or it mean " at university he studied the stars and planets of the southern hemisphere"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There **went off** means "departed, traveled away".

The stars of the southern hemisphere cannot be observed in Oxford. In 1676 Halley went to the island of St Helena in the South Atlantic.

For the "continued" meaning, we would say he **went *on*** to study.

Comment: I've edited to add a biographical detail (where Halley went off to)

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/go-off